# DeprecationWarning: How could I fix this?

Tags: python

I am making a platformer game using pygame and I got this error when the character jumps:

`DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of Python.`

This is the line of code that got the error:

```
win.blit(char, (x,y))
```

Somebody help me fix this problem!

Comment: Pass in int(x) instead of x.

Comment: Without knowing more about your code, it sounds like it wants you to explicitly convert your `float` to and `int`.  I.e., `x=int(y)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the function numbers of type float, but you should be passing integers.

You can pass the function integers instead of floats.

You can cast your floats to integers: `win.blit(char, (int(x),int(y))`. This will round the float towards 0. (e.g. `int(2.6)=2`, `int(-2.6) = -2` If you want different behaviour, you can use `round(x)`.

e.g. 
`round(2.5) = 2`
`round(2.51) = 3`